# Visual Studio 2015 Community Package Did Not Load Correctly

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and when it was done, I launched it up and came up with this big error message:

> " The
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage'
>   package did not load correctly. The problem may have been caused by a
>   configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You
>   can get more information by examining the file
>   'C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>   Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue. Continue to
>   show this error message? "

And then after I click YES or NO, it freezes Visual Studio no matter what I do! I need some help here.